# Is the number of input elements being processed the same regardless of when Linq-to-Objects operator gets called?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-objects

Even though `Select` operator gets called before the `Take` operator, the lambda expression will only get called for the first two input elements:

```
        string[] count = { "one ", "two ", "three ", "four ", "five ", "six " };
        IEnumerable<int> results = count.Select(item =>
                               {
                                      Console.WriteLine(item);
                                      return item.Length;
                               }).Take(2); 
        foreach (int i in results);
```

OUTPUT:

```
one two
```

a) Assuming we chain several Linq-to-Objects standard query operators together, is the order in which `Take` operator gets called never important? Thus, it never matters whether `Take` gets called first or last, since the number of input elements for which the lambda expression will be called is always the same?

b) Again assuming we chain several Linq-to-Objects standard query operators together, are there any other Linq-to-Objects operators where the order in which they are called doesn't affect the number of input elements for which the lambda expression gets called?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query operators typically only move as many steps forward in the source collection as they need to produce the number of required output results.

In your example `Take()` will only require 2 items from `Select()` so that's all that will be produced by `Select()`. `Select()` is probably implemented roughly like this (taken from [Jon Skeet's blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-3-quot-select-quot-and-a-rename.aspx):

```
private static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>( 
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, TResult> selector) 
{ 
    foreach (TSource item in source) 
    { 
        yield return selector(item); 
    } 
}
```

Sorting and grouping operators  will need to create the full result set before being able to return anything (e.g. `OrderBy()`).

As long as you don't use any ordering, grouping, filtering (such as with `Where()` or `Skip()`) or any other operator changing the number of items in the sequence it shouldn't matter where in the chain you put the `Take()`.

Comment: The order of `Take` is always important in relation to `Skip`, also.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: You're right, that's another kind of filtering I missed. I've clarified.

Comment: @Anders: 1) "Sorting and grouping operators will need to create the full result set before being able to return anything (e.g. OrderBy())." As far as OrderBy and Take goes, I assume where in the chain Take is called only affects the number of input elements being processed, but the resulting sequence is always in the same order?
2) Are there any other operators where ( under right conditions – such as no grouping and no ordering ) the order in which they are called is not important?

Comment: 1) If you have the sequence `{ 3, 7, 2, 4 }` `Take(2).OrderBy(i => i)` will produce { 3, 7 } while `OrderBy(i => i).Take(2)` will produce `{ 2, 4 }` which is quite different. 2) Don't know. I think the conclusion is to never, ever have side effects in the functions/lambdas used with linq.

Comment: 2) What do you mean by "never, ever have side effects"? Perhaps that I should always assume the order of operators has side effects?

Comment: A side effect is if the lambda do anything else than just returning a value based on the input, such as calling `Console.WriteLine`. It is interesting for learning, but never do it in real code.

Answer (score 1):

Order is important, but execution is typically deferred and, undoubtedly, optimized.  If your assertions/observations were correct, then adding a ToList() before Take() wouldn't affect the output, but it does.  The ToList() call acts to force full enumeration prior to the Take() and results in the Select lambda being invoked on all elements.

The lesson here is don't rely on optimizations for correctness.

```
string[] count = { "one ", "two ", "three ", "four ", "five ", "six " }; 
IEnumerable<int> results = count.Select(item => 
                           { 
                                      Console.WriteLine(item); 
                                      return item.Length; 
                           })
                          .ToList()
                          .Take(2);
```

Comment: "If your assertions/observations were correct, then adding a ToList() wouldn't affect the output, but it does"
I'm not completely sure what you're saying, since calling count.Select(item =>{Console.WriteLine(item); return item.Length;}).Take(2).ToList(); gives me the same output. In other words, lambda expression only gets called for the first two elements

Comment: @AspOnMyNet - sorry, I should have specified that it would be added between the Select and Take. Updated.